# gradle unable to deduce layout error

Tags: spring, gradle

I am getting the following error when building a sprint boot based project using Gradle.   I tried building with --debug option but that resulted in the same error and no further insights.

---

```
:clean
:compileJava
:processResources
Copy over the Env properties
Copy env properties from src/main/resources to C:\project-portal\build/resources/main/local.application.properties
:classes
:findMainClass
:war
Creating exploded war file :: C:\project-portal\build/project-portal
:bootRepackage FAILED
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':bootRepackage'.

  > Unable to deduce layout for 'C:\project-portal\build\libs\project-portal'

What does it mean by 'Unable to deduce layout'?   Thanks!

Update #1 to include the build.gradle:

```
<pre>
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.2.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'war'

def deployDir = ""
def configDir=""

def appWarName = "project-portal"

configurations.create('myConfiguration')

configurations.myConfiguration  {
    if("$appEnv"=='local') {
        configDir=localConfigDir
        deployDir=localDeployDir
    } else if("$appEnv"=='uat') {
        configDir=uatConfigDir
        deployDir=uatDeployDir
    }
    println "Config Dir :: $configDir"
    println "Deploy Dir :: $deployDir"
}


processResources {
    doLast {
        println "Copy over the Env properties"
        copy {
            println "Copy env properties from src/main/resources to $buildDir/resources/main/${appEnv}.application.properties"
            from "src/main/resources/${appEnv}.application.properties"
            into "$buildDir/resources/main/"
            rename { filename -> filename.replace "${appEnv}.application.properties", 'application.properties'}
        }
    }
}

springBoot {
    mainClass= "com.company.Application"
}

bootRepackage {
    mainClass = 'com.company.Application'
}

jar {
    baseName = 'project-portal'
    version =  ''
    exclude('src/main/resources/*.properties')
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7

dependencies {
    //compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent")
    //compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'

    testCompile("junit:junit")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")

    //hibernate
    //compile 'org.eclipse.persistence:javax.persistence:2.1.0'
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.3.8.Final'
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.3.8.Final'
    compile 'org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.2.1.Final'
    compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa'

    //Security
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")

    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.34'

    //After bug
    compile 'aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.5.4'

}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.9-rc-1'
}

war {
    archiveName="$appWarName"
    doLast {
        println "Creating exploded war file :: $buildDir/$appWarName"
        ant.unzip(src: war.archivePath, dest: "$buildDir/$appWarName")
    }
}

task copyJar(type: Copy) {
     println "Copy lib to $buildDir/lib"
     it.dependsOn jar
     from "$buildDir/libs"
     into "$buildDir/web"
}

task deployApp(type: Copy) {
     println "Copy dependencyJar to $buildDir"
     it.dependsOn copyJar
     it.dependsOn war
     from "$buildDir/$appWarName/WEB-INF/lib"
     into "$buildDir/externalJars"
     from "$buildDir/libs"
     into "$buildDir/externalJars"
     from "$buildDir/$appWarName"
     into "$deployDir/$appWarName"
}

</pre>
```

Comment: Can you paste your build.gradle to look more into the error?

Comment: See update #1 added to the original post.   Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is caused by `appWarName` variable's value. You set it to `project-portal`, and Gradle's `war` task does not add `.war` extension, so resulting war archive has full name of `project-portal` without any extension.

`bootRepackage` task tries to determine the layout of file based on its extension (see [source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-loader-tools/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/loader/tools/Layouts.java)) -  and fails, as there is no extension.

Fix is simple:

`def appWarName = "project-portal.war"`

Comment: Thanks Nikita!  That was it.

Comment: Glad, I could hlp. Accept then answer, plz

Comment: had to lookup how to accept an answer :-)   Thanks again.